# Best way to avoid embedded lists in pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas

this is quite a basic question, and has more to do with the construction of a database than actual coding.

I have a `DataFrame` looking something like this:

```
    Animal      Months 
0   Alligator   [True,True,True,True,True,False,False,True,False,True,False,True]
1   Bear        [False,False,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,False]
2   Capybara    [True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]
3   Deer        [False,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,False]
```

It describes the months in a year, that a particular species of animal is active in, as an embedded list of boolean values (for each month, January to December). What would be the best way to represent this in a robust database/`DataFrame`? Obviously an embedded list of boolean values is not very panda-esque and quite error-prone. I also want to avoid needing a dedicated column for every month.
In the end I want to be able to for example return a list of all the animals that are active in January.

Thanks a lot for your help!

P.S. Please don't worry about the fact that the data obviously doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also want to avoid needing a dedicated column for every month. In the end I want to be able to for example return a list of all the animals that are active in January.

That is actually the logical way to organize your data, in this case.

You can use

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.Months.tolist())
```

to create a DataFrame with columns for each month.

To have `Animal` too, you can use

```
as_columns_df = pd.concat([df.Animal, pd.DataFrame(df2.Months.tolist())], axis=1)
```

To set the columns to logical names, use

```
as_columns_df.columns = ['Animal', 'Jan', 'Feb', ...
```

Following that, you can use

```
as_columns_df[as_columns_df.Jan]
```

for example, which seems convenient.